# Basic Error Capture - for inputs - Python

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to error capture my variables that are set by a user input. So far I have done this but was wandering if there are any simpler or more efficient ways of doing this:

```
 while number1error == 1:
        try:
            number1 = float(input("Please enter the value of number1"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an integer")
```

As you can see this would take up a lot of space if I had a lot of inputs from the user. Any better suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is there a way i could set it to insure that the number is between something, for example to make sure that 'number 1' is between 0 and 1?

Comment: You're probably not going to attract much help stating that anyone that can give a clever solution is a "nerd."  edit: Good call deleting that comment.

Comment: For repeated tasks, investigate the use of functions

Comment: @PortableGibbon I am on StackOverflow to help people that have programming questions.  You should probably take the time to read the site's [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as you don't seem to be having much luck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help?

```
totalReTries = 10
acquiredValue = None
PROMPT_MESSAGE = "Please enter the valid value: "
typeOfInteredData = float
rangeOfData = range(10, 20)

for currentRetry in range(1, totalReTries):

    print "Attempt %d of %d" % (currentRetry, totalReTries)
    try:
        acquiredValue = input(PROMPT_MESSAGE)
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect data format. Please try again.")
        continue

    if type(acquiredValue) != typeOfInteredData:
        print "Incorrect data type. Please try again."
        continue
    elif not acquiredValue in rangeOfData:
        print "Incorrect data Range. Please try again."
        continue
    break

if not acquiredValue:
    print "ERROR: Failed to get a correct value"
else:
    print "The acquired value is: " + str(acquiredValue)
```

Adapting this into a function, as suggested above, would be a good idea too.
Regards